# Which bivariate monomials are convex?

Tags: polynomials, convex-analysis

Given $$f(x, y) = x^m y^n$$ where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, for which values of $m$ and $n$ is $f$ convex?

---

My intuition says that both $m$ and $n$ should be even. I am trying to prove this by showing that the Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite and getting a strange result.

We have
$$\nabla f = \begin{bmatrix}mx^{m-1}y^n \\ nx^m y^{n-1}\end{bmatrix} \\
Hf = \begin{bmatrix}m(m-1)x^{m-2}y^n & nmx^{m-1} y^{n-1}\\ nmx^{m-1} y^{n-1} & n(n-1)x^{m}y^{n-2}\end{bmatrix}$$

$H$ is positive semidefinite if all upper-left determinants are nonnegative. The first submatrix has $ m(m-1)x^{m-2}y^n \geq 0$ for even $m, n$. But

$$\begin{align}\det H & = \left\vert\begin{matrix}m(m-1)x^{m-2}y^n & nmx^{m-1} y^{n-1}\\ nmx^{m-1} y^{n-1} & n(n-1)x^{m}y^{n-2}\end{matrix}\right\vert \\
& = \displaystyle - m^{2} n x^{2 m-2} y^{2 n-2} - m n^{2} x^{2 m-2} y^{2 n-2} + m n x^{2 m-2} y^{2 n-2} \\
& = \left(- m^{2} n - m n^{2} + m n\right) \left(x^{2 m-2} y^{2 n-2}\right) \\
& = (1-m-n)(mn)(x^{2 m-2} y^{2 n-2})
\end{align}$$

$x^{2 m-2} y^{2 n-2}$ and $mn$ are nonnegative, so we need $1-m-n \geq 0 $, which is true for no positive integers.

This is obviously wrong, as $f(x, y) = x^2 y^2$ is positive definite.

Where is my error?

Comment: Are you focusing on convexity or positive definiteness of monomials? $x^2 y^2$ is not convex, is it?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The full question reads, "A function $f$ of 2 real variables is called a monomial if it has the form$f(x,y) = x^m y^n$ for some nonnegative integers $m$ and $n$. Which monomials are convex?" (I have restricted my question to positive $m, n$ to avoid fussy derivatives.) Source is Vanderbei, *Linear Programming: Foundations and Extensions* p. 387. Or is the point, perhaps, that no monomial is convex?

Comment: How does that answer my question? $x^2 y^2$ can be positive semidefinite but non-convex, can it not? What if none of the monomials is convex? What if your conclusion is correct?

Comment: Thank you. The statement "$x^2 y^2$ can be positive semidefinite but non-convex" identifies my error. If you post it as an answer, I will mark it as such. I assume the correct answer to the original question is then that there are no positive integers $m, n$ that make $f$ convex.

Comment: You're making another mistake. You're using Sylvester's criterion for positive definiteness to test positive *semi*definiteness. You forgot the southeast entry.

Comment: The southeast entry yields the same constraint on $m$ and $n$, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x, y) := x^2 y^2$ may be positive semidefinite, but that does not imply that it is convex. It is not.